# Select "this" element after completed ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using Jquery, after a completed ajax call, how can I say `remove()` this element you just clicked? Using the following code doesn't work:

```
$( ".deletegid" ).click(function() {   
    var imageid = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/public/index.php/admin/content/athletes/deleteimagefromgallery",
        data: {
            imageid: imageid,
            galleryid: $("input[name=athletes_gid]").val(),
            ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val()
        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        $(this).remove();           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use context option of ajax to set context to current element:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    context:this,
    url: "/public/index.php/admin/content/athletes/deleteimagefromgallery",
    data: { imageid: imageid ,galleryid: $("input[name=athletes_gid]").val(), ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val() }
})
.done(function() {
    $(this).remove();           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it in a variable

```
$(".deletegid").click(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var imageid = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/public/index.php/admin/content/athletes/deleteimagefromgallery",
            data: {
                imageid: imageid,
                galleryid: $("input[name=athletes_gid]").val(),
                ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val()
            }
        })
        .done(function() {
            obj.remove();
        });
});
```

`this` refers to ajax object in `done` event.

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
$(".deletegid").click(function() {
var objectControl = $(this);
var imageid = objectControl.attr('name');
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/public/index.php/admin/content/athletes/deleteimagefromgallery",
        data: {
            imageid: imageid,
            galleryid: $("input[name=athletes_gid]").val(),
            ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val()
        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        objectControl.remove();
    });
```

});